# AWS elastic beanstalk redirect www to non-www with nginx location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm trying to redirect www to non-www on elastic beanstalk, but I can't find any info on how to do that with nginx.

I have a location config that redirects http to https. Is there a way I can do this inside that config? I'd have to override the base nginx config to add a `server` config (which is the recommended way to do it according to the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html)), which I'd rather not do if I don't have to.

```
location / {
     set $redirect 0;
     if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
       set $redirect 1;
     }
     if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
       set $redirect 0;
     }
     if ($redirect = 1) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     }

     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     proxy_http_version  1.1;

     proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
     proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: First of all, what is the reason you don't want to use multiple server blocks? It's much clearer that way. Second, be careful with the if : https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ ifs are evil in nginx. I'll put somehow what you need to do to make what you want to work in 1 location.

Comment: I can't add a server block to the elastic beanstalk nginx config without overriding the entire configuration, which I haven't been able to do without screwing up the environment.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, I would use different server blocks. If you don't want, I would use the logic on $redirect as a boolean, and redirect hardcoding the $host, you want it without www anyway, don't you? Would this fit in what you want to do?:

```
location / {
     set $redirect 0;
     if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
       set $redirect 1;
     }
     if ($host != "www.example.com") {
       set $redirect 1;
     }
     if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
       set $redirect 0;
     }
     if ($redirect = 1) {
       return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
     }

     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     proxy_http_version  1.1;

     proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
     proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

like this you end with only 1 redirect to the correct scheme://host . Or is there anything else you are configuring in this location block that I need to consider?

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I ended up finding another answer that solved it in a way that doesn't require me to specify the domain name, which is nice for other environments too!

`if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)) {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
    }`